# Using Python in a Website

Tags: javascript, python, html, web, onclick

I have a very cool game that I made with python and I wish to turn it into  an even cooler website. Im experienced using javascript, html, and css. Can I make it so I click on a div and use "onClick" to run python? Or does it only work with javascript? How can I do something like this?

Thanks!

Comment: Python doesn't run natively in any web browser, but maybe you should have a look at this project that compiles python to javascript: http://pyjs.org/

Comment: You will probably have to resort to Ajax calls or Brython ("Python in the Browser") https://bitbucket.org/olemis/brython/src

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google App Engine to make nicely Web application like your game for free.

Here is there tutorial how to build web application in there engine with python: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/introduction

Enjoy :)